# Issue of upper case & lower case in rewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this code in my htaccess to redirect people who try to access any url that contains query string "username=richard".

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)username=richard(&|$)
RewriteRule .* /? [R,L]
```

The above code works great if someone enter:

```
example.com/folder.php?username=richard
```

But i found that it's not working if someone enter upper case in the string value:

```
example.com/folder.php?username=Richard
```

or

```
example.com/folder.php?username=riChard
```

and etc..

So how to solve the upper/lower cases problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add No case flag:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)username=richard(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /? [R,L]
```